# Report Google web search results that contain offensive images

Tags: google-search, google-safesearch

In Google Image Search, it's possible to report individual offensive images. How can I report web pages (or entire websites) that contain offensive images? These pages occasionally show up in search results, even with SafeSearch enabled.

Comment: A related question: Is it possible to report an image by entering the image's URL (instead of finding the image via Google Search)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has [a reporting tool for objectionable content](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/safesearch?pli=1&grid.sortBy=3&grid.currentOrder=3d), such as websites and images. If websites aren't correctly filtered, you can submit them here. In addition to this, if you see objectionable or illegal content, you should report it by going here: https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en
You can also go here, if the first link doesn’t work for you: https://reportharmfulcontent.com/

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest is to use the Google Feedback tool and report the image not being properly filtered by SafeSearch. I have the steps in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37061).

In addition to this, if you see objectionable or illegal content, I recommend reporting it by going here: https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en
You can also go here, if the first link doesn’t work: https://reportharmfulcontent.com/

Comment: Was this answer intended for this question instead, since this answer would be more relevant there? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36971/is-it-possible-to-report-false-positives-for-google-safesearch You answered one of my questions, but it appears that this answer was posted on the wrong page somehow. :)

Comment: Hmm, seems like a likely answer for both :D

Comment: You can post this as an answer on that question, then. My other question hasn't been answered yet. :)

Comment: Today, I found that Google has [a reporting tool for this specific purpose](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40515/20087), so it isn't necessary to use Google Feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you see objectionable or illegal content you should report it, by going here: https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en
You can also go here, if the first link doesn’t work: https://reportharmfulcontent.com/