# Is it possible to report false positives for Google SafeSearch?

Tags: google-search, google-safesearch

I've noticed that Google SafeSearch often filters images that should not be filtered - this is especially true since the "off - moderate - strict" options were removed, and replaced with a simple "on/off" switch. Since this change was implemented, I've noticed that many inoffensive images have been filtered. Is there any way to report non-offensive images that are filtered by SafeSearch (so that these false positives can be resolved)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google Feedback tool as shown [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37061/is-it-possible-to-use-google-feedback-in-google-search) and report to Google regarding the inoffensive image being filtered. I believe there is a mechanism on their side to check if an image is being filtered by SafeSearch.