# Is it possible to use Google Feedback in Google Search?

Tags: google-search, google-feedback

Is it possible to use Google Feedback on Google Search? I want to suggest some improvements to make to Google Search's user interface. I've figured out how to use Google Feedback on Google+ and Youtube, but I still haven't found it for Google Search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link to the Google Feedback tool is always available at the bottom of the page of a search result.

Click on the "Give us feedback" link to add a comment and capture a portion of the webpage that you are referring to.

[image: Google Feedback is available under the third link from the right]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything there natively on each search page. There is a [quality form](http://www.google.com/quality_form), not sure whether it still works.

[image]

Comment: See the latest answer to this question - there's a "give us feedback" link at the bottom of every search results page.