# Google Search language settings keep resetting

Tags: google-search, localization

On a Google search results page, I go to Settings -> Languages and set desired language preferences.

However, on the next day language setting reset to what seems to be regional defaults.

I'm always logged in and I'm using Google on Windows, Linux and Android devices. My browser is Chrome.

How do I persist language settings?

Comment: This looks like a bug that should be reported to Google by using [tag:google-feedback] --> https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37061/88163

Comment: did you check if you dont have your search engine saved in chrome as regional one?

Comment: user0, ah, that may be the case! I've switched the Chrome search option to use `google.com`. Hopefully, that will do the trick. Meanwhile, can you please post your suggestion as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by using a regional version of Google (google.ru) as the default search engine in Chrome.

Switching to google.com resolved the issue for me.

Kudos to [user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471/user0) for the solution.